# Rails(4.2) でカテゴリ毎にサブディレクトリでサイトを構成する方法について

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

わかりにくいタイトルですみません。

サブディレクトリでカテゴリを指定し、それぞれで構成が同一のサイトを運営したいと考えています。
例えば、example.com/car/articles が車に関する記事一覧、example.com/car/shops が車販売店一覧
example.com/bike/articles がバイクに関する記事一覧、example.com/bike/shops がバイク販売店一覧のような感じです。

/categories/(car|bike) のよにすれば良いではないかと突っ込まれそうですが、carのトップページをexample.com/car に、bikeのトップページをexample.com/bike に集中させようと考えているため、/car、/bike の下に、restfulなURL設計を行いたいと考えています。
ちなみにcar,bikeにかかわらず、それ以下の構成は同一にしようと考えています。

現在、

```
namespace :main, :path => "/:category" do
  resources :articles
  resources :shops
```

のようにroutesを設定しており、リンクを貼る際は

```
= link_to "name", [:main, @article, :category => @category_name]   # @category_name = params[:category]
```

のような形で何とか動いているのですが、:category を指定するのが冗長な気がします。
こういったケースをうまく処理するgood practiceはあるのでしょうか。

ご教示お願いします。

Comment: 1つの rails プログラムで動かすイメージですか？(DB1つですか?) それとも1つのプログラムを同じサーバで複数動かすイメージでしょうか？

Comment: 1つのrailsプログラムで、DBも1つです。

Answer (score 2):

自分が同じ状況でしたら、下記のように書くと思います。

```
%i(car bike).each do |category|
   namespace category do
     resources :articles
     resources :shops
   end
end
```

そうすると、下記のように routes が生成されます。

```
car_articles GET    /car/articles(.:format)           car/articles#index
....
bike_articles GET    /bike/articles(.:format)          bike/articles#index
```

確認していませんが、下記で動くかも……？

```
= link_to "name", [@category_name, @article]
```

Comment: `link_to`の件の参考リンクです。 http://railsguides.jp/routing.html#%E3%82%AA%E3%83%96%E3%82%B8%E3%82%A7%E3%82%AF%E3%83%88%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89%E3%83%91%E3%82%B9%E3%81%A8url%E3%82%92%E4%BD%9C%E6%88%90%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B